# Processing multiple images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing, image-segmentation

I am performing some image segmentation/processing on a series of images(about 100) in a folder. Those images are actually seperate frames from a video.

So whatever I am doing is working but it is just taking a long time to process all the images. Is there any other way to make the process faster?

Here is how it is being done:
(1) load images in cell array
(2) Go through cell array take out each images and send it to the appropriate functions
(3) Display the returned ones

Thanks

So this is how I am doing it:

```
A = size(handles.sortedImage_depth);
tic

for k = 1: A(1,1)

handles.depth_img =       imread(fullfile(handles.myFolderdepth,handles.sortedImage_depth{k})); %loads one depth image

handles.color_img = imread(fullfile(handles.myFoldercolor,handles.sortedImage_color{k})); %loads one color image

[unRGB, unDepth] = undistort(handles.color_img,handles.depth_img);%undistorts the depth n color
[mapped_depth] = depth_mapping(unDepth); %Maps the depth images to a bigger Resolution
handles.depth_mapped{k} = mapped_depth; %saves the resulting images in a cell array

[coordinates] = segmentation(handles,unRGB); %performs image segmentation on RGB

handles.allcoordinates = coordinates;
EE{k} = handles.allcoordinates;
end
EE
toc
```

Comment: The only opimization I can think of (with the information you provide) is load each image, process it, and then load the next image, overwriting the current one. That way you don't need to hold all images in memory, which might be slowing things down if they require a lot of memory (disk paging)

Comment: I would also add that using regular arrays instead of cell arrays might help a bit. Without seeing your code its hard to be more precise than than.

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description. It loads one or two images at a time, not all images at once as you wrote in the question

Comment: Run your code using `profile` and check the results.

Comment: Sorry my bad this is the last changes that I made like an hour ago. I was trying different things and the time is taken is about the same.

Comment: Would changing the individual images to a video make it faster to process? I am not too familiar with video processing aswell but I was just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of your functions which operate on each image, it is hard to say, but you might be able to convert your code to GPU processing (which is usually much faster). For a look at how to convert MATLAB code to be GPU based, here are a few helpful links:

[GPU-arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/establish-arrays-on-a-gpu.html) (the file format which tells MATLAB to try GPU processing)

[Element-wise GPU-enabled functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-element-wise-matlab-code-on-a-gpu.html)